# How to write sequelize transaction in type script

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

im using sequelize, node js and type script. i need to convert following command to type script.

```
return sequelize.transaction().then(function (t) {
  return User.create({
    firstName: 'Homer',
    lastName: 'Simpson'
  }, {transaction: t}).then(function (user) {
    return user.addSibling({
      firstName: 'Lisa',
      lastName: 'Simpson'
    }, {transaction: t});
  }).then(function () {
    return t.commit();
  }).catch(function (err) {
    return t.rollback();
  });
});
```

Can any one help me to solve this or give some examples regarding sequlize transaction in type script

thank you in advances

Answer (score 1):

Example

```
   return sequelize.transaction((t:Sequelize.Transaction) => {
        return User.create({
              firstName: 'Homer',
              lastName: 'Simpson'
            }, {transaction: t})
            .then((user) => {
                return user.addSibling({
                  firstName: 'Lisa',
                 lastName: 'Simpson'
               }, {transaction: t});
            })
        });
    });
```

Ref http://ngerakines.me/2016/04/11/sequelize/

Comment: Care to explain ? 
Also all I wanted to know was what would be used to import sequelize, its not compiling on my end.

Comment: @AdeelShekhani The sequelize is the object of `Sequelize();` which you get when you make connection to the database. This is how you would create it:
`const sequelize = new Sequelize();`